# Is it possible to use Silverlight RiaServices without IIS?

Tags: silverlight, ria, wcf-ria-services, partial-trust

I want to use silverlight as my windows service interface. For that, I'm using a custom web server to provide the xap file and it works fine.

Now I want to use RiaServices, but of course I there is no IIS involved.

Here is my code:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class TestDomainService : DomainService {

    public IQueryable<Foo> GetPontos() {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
        list.Add(new Foo {Id = 1});
        return list.AsQueryable();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And Program:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {      
      DomainServiceHost host = new DomainServiceHost(typeof(TestDomainService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:8099/TestDomainService"));
      host.Open();
}
```

You can use this code in an empty cmd application and once you hit play, a runtime exception is thrown:

System.TypeAccessException was unhandled Message=Attempt by security transparent method 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainTypeDescriptionProvider.GetForeignKeyMembers()' to access security critical type System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociationAttribute' failed.
Assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain.
  Source=System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server
  TypeName=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainTypeDescriptionProvider.GetForeignKeyMembers()
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainTypeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, Object instance)
       at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
       at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Type componentType)
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.AddEntityType(Type entityType)
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.AddQueryMethod(DomainOperationEntry method)
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.Initialize()
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.CreateDescription(Type domainServiceType)
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_7(Type type)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.GetDescription(Type domainServiceType)
       at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
       at PartialTrustTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Users\carlucci\Documents\My Dropbox\My Dropbox\Way2\PartialTrustTest\PartialTrustTest\Program.cs:line 10
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.Th

readHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

---

I tried to add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to the APTCA, but no success :(

I changed my application to run in full trust, but no success :(

Any idea?

Comment: If you're running in debug mode, be sure to go to the Project Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" and you will stop getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible, but here's a full code listing that provides RIA with OData which is consumable by Excel PowerPivot. Remember that you must turn off the visual studio hosting process, or just run without debugging. When using PowerPivot remember to include the trailing slash so your URL will be: http://localhost:999/TestDomainService/

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
       public partial class Program
       {
              [EnableClientAccess]
              public class TestDomainService : DomainService
              {
                     [Query(IsDefault=true)]
                     public IQueryable<Foo> GetAllFoos()
                     {
                           return new Foo[] { new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Jonathan" } }.AsQueryable();
                     }
              }

              public class Foo
              {
                     [Key]
                     public int Id { get; set; }
                     public string Name { get; set; }
              }

              static void Main(string[] args)
              {
                     var svc = new DomainServiceHost(typeof(TestDomainService), new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:999/TestDomainService") });
                     svc.Description.Behaviors.RemoveAll<AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute>();

                     var svcDescription = DomainServiceDescription.GetDescription(typeof(TestDomainService));
                     var endpoints = new ODataEndpointFactory().CreateEndpoints(svcDescription, svc);

                     svc.Description.Endpoints.Clear();

                     foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
                     {
                           svc.Description.Endpoints.Add(endpoint);
                     }

                     svc.Open();

                     Console.WriteLine("Domain service started, press any key to exit.");
                     Console.ReadKey();
              }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RIA Services without IIS. Configure the domain service before opening:

```
DomainServiceHost host = new DomainServiceHost(typeof(DomainService1), uri);
host.Description.Behaviors.Remove<AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute>();
```

Also check the *.config of your exe-file, as I remember there was some settings related to IIS which you have to remove.

And also in the project properties in VS, open "Debug" tab and uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".